# Remove repeated values and display only one from firebas

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist

I'm using Adapter to retrieve data from firebase and I want to remove the repeated values from an arraylist.

Here is my data structure

```
-Hotels
   -ID
      -location : "USA"
   -ID1
      -location : "USA"
   -ID2
      -location : "CANADA"
```

My current output is {"USA", "USA", "CANADA"}
What I want to display is {"USA", "CANADA"}

My code 
//Global

```
ArrayList loca = new Array`enter code here`List<>();
```

//oncreate

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(Datasnapshot dataSnapshot){
     for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         Hotels hotels = postSnapshot.getValue(Hotels.class);
         String location = hotels.getLocation();
         String lo = setLocation(location);
         loca.add(new Hotels(lo));
         HashSet<Hotels> hs = new HashSet<>(loca);
         loca.clear();
         loca.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yup why? I used <String>